# Compare two DATETIME fields from multidimensional array and return a value or index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have a user table. I have 2 `DATETIME` per row that I'm looking at. I will look at `$lastLog` date and `$lastReceived` (for last received lead) and determine which is newer and that becomes their `$eligibleTime`. We will then look for the oldest `$eligibleTime` to select which user should receive the lead. I am filtering through users to make sure they are licensed in the appropriate state that the lead is in and also that they haven't reached their daily quota.

I'm thinking maybe I built the multi-d array wrong and should have grouped instead all of the `$lastLog` dates and `$lastReceived` dates into their own arrays and run `max($array)` or something like this.

How can I look at this? I've built a multidimensional array using:

```
    $sql = "SELECT `lastLog`,`firstName`,`lastReceived` FROM customers";
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $result = array();
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
      $result[] = $line;
    }
```

It is returning the following data:

```
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [lastLog] => 2015-06-12 02:00:00 [firstName] => Nathaniel [lastReceived] => 2015-06-12 05:16:10 ) [1] => Array ( [lastLog] => 2015-06-12 01:00:00 [firstName] => Ignacio [lastReceived] => 2015-06-01 10:00:00 ) [2] => Array ( [lastLog] => 2015-06-12 00:00:00 [firstName] => James [lastReceived] => 2015-06-08 00:00:00 ) [3] => Array ( [lastLog] => 2015-06-12 04:00:00 [firstName] => Robert [lastReceived] => 2015-06-10 00:00:00 ) )
```

Thank you, nate

Comment: easy enough: `select greatest(lastlog, lastreceived) AS eligibletime`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: got it.. thanks. this worked once I figured out how to implement it. oddly PHPMyAdmin wouldn't let me run that sql for some reason... the query works in my php script though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marc B this got solved.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,
   "SELECT firstName, greatest(lastLog, lastReceived) AS eligibleTime 
    FROM customers 
    ORDER BY eligibleTime DESC
    LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
print_r($result);
```